# Not able to upgrade .Net framework version for SSIS Script tasks

Tags: ssis, .net-4.5, sql-server-data-tools, .net-4.7.2, ssis-2017

I have SSDT 2017 and VS 2017 with .Net framework version 4.7.2, I have few old ssis scripts tasks written with .Net 4.5 now i need to upgrade those with .Net 4.7.2, But when i update script projects with .Net 4.7.2 then it always back reverts to .Net 4.5. Please help !